# How do I make a pointer for a vector inside a vector?

Tags: c++

I have this currently:

```
vector<int> *ptrvec1;
vector<vector<int> > *ptrvec2;
vector<vector<int> > vec;
ptrvec1 = ?????
ptrvec2 = &vec;
```

and I want to associate the `ptrvec1` to the address of the vector inside `vec`.

The problem is that the exterior vec lenght is not constant, it depends of the user input

not 3 and 10 vectors. that's the vector lenght...

imagine you have the vector with adress 0, 1 and 2
each one of those adresses has another vector. I want to run the pointer in each vector inside the 0, 1 and 2 adress

```
0,    0, 1, 2
1,    0, 1, 2
2,    0, 1, 2
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?  What does *"the vector inside vec"*, mean if there are any number of vectors inside `vec`, including possibly 0 vectors.

Comment: the outside vector may vary between 3 and 10 total lenght. Each vector inside of the vector possesses the same lengh.

Comment: If there are between 3 and 10 vectors, which one of them is *"the vector"* in your question?

Comment: Based on your most recent edit, NPE's answer seems to exactly answer your question.  That's how to get pointers to the various vectors.

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

```
ptrvec1 = &vec[0];
```

assuming, of course, that `vec` contains at least one element (which in the code you show it doesn't).

Replace `0` with the required index.

Comment: The problem is that the exterior vec lenght is not constant, it depends of the user input